# Dynamics CRM Preserve Global Array Values during OnSave Event

Tags: javascript, arrays, global, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I've written some code for custom entities that dynamically presents questions that the user must answer. The code creates answer records, that are then associated with it's parent record.

My issue is that I'd like users to be able to complete the answers BEFORE having to save the record for which they are answering the questions. The problem is that in order to associate the answers records to a parent record, the parent record must have a guid value, and this is only created once the record is saved.

My idea is that I can store the answer record guid values in a global array, and OnSave of the parent record, go update the answer records accordingly to link them to the parent. BUT when I save the record, my global gets wiped clean.

Is there any way to preserve the values stored in that global array? Or does anyone have a more clever way to route around this issue? Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: How do you `present questions that the user must answer`? Are these questions attributes on the entity?

Comment: They are displayed through an HTML web resource, and the questions are actual records. So no, they are not attributes on the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping in mind that you're using a HTML Web Resource and you will have access to the Global Context, I can think in these alternatives:

- Force the user to manually save the record: I know that you want to avoid this option, but this behaviour would be similar to the one that the grids have (they show a message which says "To enable this content, save the record"). You can accomplish this using the [Form Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327828.aspx#BKMK_getFormType).
- Save the temporary data in a hidden field: instead of using a global array to save the answers you can use a hidden field in your parent entity so the data will be preserved. You will be able to create the related entities when the form loads again (to reuse the code that you have in place now) or use a plugin (Post Create of your parent entity).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say to save the answers in a hidden field -- if I have an array of say 3 guids, would I use a lookup field that can hold all of the guids as individual records? Or are you thinking of something different?

Comment: To be honest, my first though was a text field where you can store your data as JSON for instance.

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes sense. Thanks! I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: I think this approach is going to prove successful, BUT I'm having trouble dealing with parsing/stringifying the JSON object in order to add an attribute to the child record after the parent record saves and the code reads the hidden field holding the value. I need to add an attribute to every object in an array that has been parsed into json in order to be held in the hidden field. Should I parse the json into javascript, add the attribute and re-stringify?

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if I understood your question. Could you please add some code to make it clearer?